# Insert command not showing schema details

Tags: postgresql

I need to back up a table from a database schema.The table is located under `kdb28_test_h` and a schema named `kref`. I tried with the following code

```
pg_dump --host=110.11.12.16 --port=5432 --username=db_root --password --column-inserts \n 
    --table=kref.abc kdb28_test_h > test_h_popl_back_up.sql
```

but insert command is generating like

```
insert into abc(----);
```

but I need

```
insert into kref.abc(------)
```

Answer (score 4):

That's fine because your dump should have the following:

```
SET search_path = kref, pg_catalog;
```

and then table definition followed by insert statements

Comment: @user1782877: [More about the schema search path in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)